# Make data from another sheet to goes into respective row in master sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I got a "new" sheet that will be generated few times a day, and it will be deleted after this sub.

I want to copy data from "new" sheet and paste it into existing
    "records" sheet

1. paste data into its respective row (different fruits)
2. add new fruit row if fruit doesn't exist in "records" sheet
3. sort from (a-z), the entire used range in "records" sheet by first column of fruit name
4. fill zero for found blank cell in used range
5. add a total row to the last used range row + 1 (so it will be different whenever this sheet run for new stall order)

[image: eg]

Sheet : Records, new, how I want it
In this case, you may take note on the Banana, Blueberry and Dragonfruit

I'm now getting the error for "Block If without End If".
Updates: I missed the End If for finding blankCol. Now the code doesn't have error but I can't get the results that I want.
[image: This is my current record sheet]
I have no idea what went wrong in the code as the banana, blueberry should be added as new fruits in "Records", but now I get an extra Strawberry in the list, think it should be smtg about the else condition, but I don't know how to fix it.

For now I only get to the 2nd part of my requirements, as I am not too familiar with used range yet, I'm still having a little struggle in coding it.

```
Sub fruit()

'find first blank column
blankCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Records").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If blankCol > 1 Then
blankCol = blankCol + 1
End If

'paste the list into existing "Records" sheet
Set rsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Records")
Set r = rsht.Range("A1") 'record sheet

'set up header for new entry in "Records"
r.Offset(0, blankCol - 1).Value = "new" 'new sheet name from different stalls
r.Offset(1, blankCol - 1).Value = "Amount"

'new sheet with new data
Set temp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("new")
Set n = temp.Range("A1") 'temp : new

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = temp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row in new temp sheet

Dim nextrow As Long
nextrow = rsht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find next empty row in "Records"

    j = 2 '"Records" sheet
    For i = 1 To lastrow 'refer new

        If n.Offset(i, 0).Value = r.Offset(j, 0).Value Then 'if name matched then

            r.Offset(j, blankCol - 1).Value = n.Offset(i, 1).Value 'copy respective value

        Else

            'paste new name into next available row
            r.Offset(nextrow, 0).Value = n.Offset(i, 0).Value 'fruits
            r.Offset(nextrow, blankCol - 1).Value = n.Offset(i, 1).Value 'amount

        End If

    j = j + 1        
    Next i

End Sub

'delete that new sheet
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("new").Delete
```

Comment: 1/ `last` is undefined 2/ `for` is missing a `next` [For...Next Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx). These are the obvious errors. There may well be more ...

Comment: Start debugging by settings a breakpoint on a line of code in the editor, then step through your code one line at a time until you find out exactly what line is causing the error.

Comment: ...you are missing an `End If`.  I assume it should come after `Next i`?

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, the error has been resolved. I have updates in the above question. Strange that the list stopped halfway. would you mind to shed me some light?

Comment: Hi @BruceWayne, If [condition] Then [statement]  

Else  [statements]  

End If  


---Saw this on MS webpage. I don't understand why adding an extra End If will solve the error. Do you mind to tell me why?

Comment: @ExcelNovice ah! was that `End If` right before the end of the sub always there? If so, sorry! I totally missed it then.